# Cloud Functions - User custom claims returns undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I created a new user using custom token with additional claims.

I can able to **access the claims in Firestore security rules** but in **cloud functions it returns undefined.**

Code for creating user:

```
admin.auth()
.createCustomToken(uid, claims)
.then(token => {
    console.log(token);
 });
```

Code for getting created user:

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
.then((userRecord) => { 

 console.log(userRecord.customClaims);

});
```

**userRecord.customClaims returns undefined**

Comment: This code should work. You should share your entire code, in particular the part of the code that creates a new user and set the Claims.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for the reply. I updated the code. Please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `setCustomUserClaims()`. Not `createCustomToken()`.

```
admin.auth()
.setCustomUserClaims(uid, claims)
.then(token => {
    console.log(token);
 });
```

`setCustomUserClaims()` is always override, so I recommend to get current customClaims and merge.

It depends on the situation, I recommend to use async/await.

Like this.

```
async function setClaims(uid, claims) {
    try {
        const userRecord = await admin.auth().getUser(uid);
        return await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {
            ...userRecord.customClaims,
            ...claims
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

See

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#set-custom-user-claims
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#create-custom-token
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

### Updated

#### `setCustomUserClaims()`

> Sets additional developer claims on an existing user identified by the provided uid

See

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#set-custom-user-claims

#### `createCustomToken()`

> Creates a new Firebase custom token (JWT) that can be sent back to a client device to use to sign in with the client SDKs' signInWithCustomToken() methods.
>
> You can also optionally specify additional claims to be included in the custom token. For example, below, a premiumAccount field has been added to the custom token, which will be available in the auth / request.auth objects in your Security Rules:

It's only available in the auth / request.auth objects in your Security Rules. So not set user customClaims.

See

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#create-custom-token

Comment: Thanks for the answer. setCustomUserClaims is used to override the claims. But I already set the claims during user create (createCustomToken). My question is I can able to access the claims in Firestore security rules but it return undefined in cloud functions. I updated the question kindly check it.

Comment: OK. It's seems to Your Code is correct. Could you debug `uid` is same? (at set/get). I can get claims using `userRecord.customClaims` normally.

Comment: My uid is correct. I logged the `userRecord` everything shows. But custom claims is undefined. Can you please check using the code I used? I think its a bug.

Comment: I think it works only when I set the claims using `setCustomUserClaims`. But why we need to override the claims which is already set during user create. `createCustomToken(uid, claims)`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer  !